# JetBrains PhpStorm / DataGrip introspecting Oracle database error

Tags: database, oracle, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

On PhpStorm version 2017.1.3 but I think that this error is present on any JetBrains IDE with database support.

When I choose to synchronize an Oracle schema, some objects like triggers are not shown on database and I found an error on the log.

[image: Introspecting Oracle database error]

I could not find any reason and it was working on older PhpStorm / DataGrip version (before 2016.1)

In the options tab I've added an object filter. Without it there are 5000+ tables. Even removing the regular expression on the object filter I still have the same error.

Capture of Options and Advance Options. The oracle client used is Thin.

[image: Connection Options]

Comment: What version again? You have mentioned 2017.3 (time traveller? latest is 2017.1.x only) and 2016.1 (1 year old release).

Comment: You are totally right, I've edit the question to fix it. The correct version is 2017.1.3. I'm not sure which was the version where it was working or the other possibility is that something change on the database. On the other hand, Toad can inspect the schema without any warning or error and I see the triggers and every object. The problem is that I hate Toad... jejeje

Comment: Please show your Database settings, Options tab in particular

Comment: Sorry, no further ideas from my end. The option which I was thinking about ("JDBC Metadata") seems to be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your connection properties check if you are using **Thin** Driver and change it to change to **OCI**. 
[image: Connection properties - driver]